# Function as argument for another function

Tags: python, function, arguments

The first function adds two numbers, the second function adds them twice. What is the purpose of Z? I get that x and y are the numbers you're adding together. But what is Z?

```
    def add(x, y):
return x + y

    def twice(z, x, y):
return z(z(x, y), z(x, y))

    a = 5
    b = 10
    print(twice(add, a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

`z` represents the function that you want to execute twice. In your example:

```py
twice(add, a, b)
```

`twice` received three arguments, `add`, `a`, and `b`. `add` is a reference to the `add` function, and becomes `z` instead the `twice` function. You might imagine a scenario in which you pass a different hypothetical function `subtract` to `twice`.

Answer (score 0):

In `twice(z, x, y)`, `z` is a function. So when you call `twice(add, a, b)`, `z` is the *function* `add`. Therefore `return z(z(x, y), z(x, y))` would be

```py
return add(add(a, b), add(a, b))
```

So it calculates `(a + b) + (a + b)`.

If you pass, for example, a function `sub = lambda x, y: x - y`, then `twice(sub, a, b)` will return `sub(sub(a, b), sub(a, b))` instead, i.e., `(a - b) - (a - b)`.

Another example:

```py
print(twice(lambda x, y: x + ' ' + y, 'hello', 'world'))
# hello world hello world
```